# Can't figure out why getInstance is undefined

Tags: php, backend

I'm trying to create a singleton DAO class for a project and I can't figure out why the getInstance method is coming back undefined.

I'm getting this error:

> "project/read.php:37: Fatal Error: Call to undefined method MiteDAO::getInstance"

Also, I'm running this on Tomcat8 with Quercus, where can I find the log where the stacktrace is printed? I think I've checked everything today in the logs directory and I'm not seeing it.

(this is my first time doing this)

This script is called from the front end on submit

```
<?php
ob_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

include 'MiteDAO.php';
include 'Contributer.php';

//FORM VALUES
$_cname = $_POST['cname'];
$_sname = $_POST['sname'];
$_sdate = $_POST['sdate'];
$_edate = $_POST['edate'];

$db_read_query = "select * 
    from contributes 
    where cname = '{$_cname}' and 
        sname = '{$_sname}' and 
        cdate > '{$_sdate}' and 
        cdate < '{$_edate}';";

echo "<p> From $_sdate to $_edate, $_cname made the following contributions to Senator $_sname </p>";

$db_dao = MiteDAO::getInstance();
$results = $db_dao->query($db_read_query);

$Contributers[];
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
    $temp_contrib = new Contributer();
    $temp_contrib->sname = $row[0];
    $temp_contrib->cname = $row[1];
    $temp_contrib->cdate = $row[2];
    $temp_contrib->amt = $row[3];
    array_push (Contributers, $temp_contrib);
}

echo array_values(Contributers); //TODO
?>
```

This is the MiteDAO class where getInstance is defined

```
<?php

class MiteDAO {

    private static $instance;
    private $conn;

    public static function getInstance() {

        if ($instance === null) {
            self::$instance = new MiteDAO();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function connect() {
        $conn = pg_connect ("host=localhost
                    port=5432
                    dbname=postgres
                    user=shepard
                    password=p4ssw0rd
                    connect_timeout=5")
            or die ("connection failed");
    }

    public function close() {
        pg_close ($conn);
    }

    public static function query($query) {
        return pg_query ($conn, $query) or die ('Query failed');
    }
}
?>
```

For now.. these two files are in the same directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reference the static var with `self::`

```
if (is_null(self::$instance)) {
    self::$instance = new MiteDAO();
}

return self::$instance;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

**EDIT**

You have errors in your main script:

> Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in /project/read.php on line 26

If you're trying to create an array, you need to do:

```
$contributors = array();  // use lower case for variable names, too
```

This also invalid:

```
array_push (Contributers, $temp_contrib);  // Reference your variable with a $
```

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Im still getting the same error though. "project/read.php:37: Fatal Error: Call to undefined method MiteDAO::getInstance"

Comment: I'll take another look, but the above stands as true.  Also - please always include such pertinent error messages in your question.

Comment: Updated my answer.  Trying running `php -l [php_file_name]` to make sure you don't have any errors.